# Prevent :bd from closing window in VIM

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get using to working in VIM with split windows.

So.... I split my VIM into two windows using `ctrl V S`, and I switch between windows using `ctrl W W`.

I'm using to typing `:bd` to delete the current buffer. Unfortunately, that has a side effect of closing the current window.

Is there a way to delete the buffer without closing current window ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a custom command, often named `:Kwbd` (keep window, buffer delete). There is an entire discussion and several alternatives on the [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Deleting_a_buffer_without_closing_the_window).
See also [this plugin on vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2103).